# Hide or Remove Left Border When Collapsing to Small Screen Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 divs that collapse nicely into one long column when phone size is reached.

I added a left blue border to the second div which creates a really nice vertical devider between the 2 "columns".

However, I would like to hide the border or remove at the place that the columns combine into one.

Not sure how to do this with the classes already implimented in the div. The border looks clunky and useless once screen is small enough.

Here is the working 2nd div.

```
 <div class="border col-md-6"  style="border-left:2px solid royalblue;">
```

all classes are vanilla bootstrap.js files

Comment: hey can you provide some code or demo working fiddle.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

use this @media

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

      .border
      {
        border:0px solid !important
        }


      }
```

Comment: That worked. I had to put an extra "@" in front of @media because @ is a reserved word in Razor: @@media.
I did make the 767 higher and probably need to tweak it a little.

Answer (score 1):

.col-md- class as per [bootstrap] (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) will apply for width >= 992px.

You can also try experimenting with other classes like .col-xs- .col-sm- .col-lg-

here is a sample code. hope it helps...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
        @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
            .custom-border-left {
                border-left: 2px solid royalblue;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>First div</p>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-border-left col-md-6">
            <p>Second div</p>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //js code in here
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

      .border
      {
        border:0px solid !important
        }


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new stylenew.css file & paste this css below into that and attach like this `<link href="stylenew.css" rel="stylesheet">` into your html in `<head>` tag.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:767px){
  .border{
    border: 0 solid !important
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, but where do I put it? I tried putting in a style tag and got all sorts of red lines. I tried it without the style tag and same thing.

Comment: Got the red lines to go away using "Clean" but I get this error: CS0103: The name 'media' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a media query and put your conditional styles inside of it. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .border {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
```