# How can I remove border when It becomes a menu dropdown? (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar with 3 "items". In small screens this navigation bar becomes a menu dropdown. During full screen navigarion bar I have a border-right of 1px in "nav-item-1" (Item 1). How can I remove that border when it becomes a menu dropdown? Btw, I´m using the Angular framework and HTML5, SCSS, TypeScript, Bootstrap 4.
I have this in the header.html:

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav col-10">
          <li class="nav-item-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#main">Item 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

My scss for the border on the "nav-item-1":

```
.nav-item-1{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 125%;
   }
```

When it becomes a menu dropdown (small screens) the border is still there and it`s ugly. How can I remove it when it becomes menu dropdown, but keep it in "normal" navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

In jscript create a function that when the menu becomes a dropdown it adds a class, such as "borderless", to the items (and removes it when the menu returns to normal).

In CSS modify it so the class has no border.

Comment: I don´t know how to do that, I´m still new to it... Btw, I`m using TypeScript, Bootstrap, HTML5, SCSS.  If you know how to do it step by step, could you tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

if u want a Typescript solution then use [[ngClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<div [ngClass]="{'nav-item-border': navHasBorder}"></div>
```

ngClass dynamically add or remove ur class on an element when navHasBorder is true or false respectively.

If u want More advance typescript Solution Use [Layout](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-breakpoints-angular-cdk) from CDK
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s2qlxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
[image]

Comment: Hi, it didn´t work. Probably cause I did something wrong, I don´t know much about typescript... I tried something, said that property isNotSmall$ does not exist on type "HeaderComponent". Btw, only the "nav-item-1" has a border "border-right", that`s the border I want to remove when in small screen. Can you say/show how should I do it step by step please, accordingly to my code that I showed in my question?

Comment: isNotSmall$ you have to create it in ur HeaderComponent.ts file 
Please follow links that I have provided in answer.
one is how ngClass work
one is for layout how it work in angular 
ane is stackblitz example that i had created for u by using layout.

Answer (score 0):

I found the asnwer to my question in a different question:

[Hide or Remove Left Border When Collapsing to Small Screen Using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027191/hide-or-remove-left-border-when-collapsing-to-small-screen-using-bootstrap)

Use:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

      .border
      {
        border:0px solid !important
        }


      }
```

".border" may change, dependes on the name of the class, in my case is ".nav-item-1". Number of px (767px) may also change, dependes on what you want.